# Ways of checking an unexpected user input

Tags: c, validation, input

I have learned that one should never trust user's input. It has become an habit to check it before processing it. I use that type of functions almost always, and *often wonders if there is a difference between those two versions*.

Here is a simple example of what my checking functions look like :

**Version 1**

```
int checkASCII(char c) // Here we check, print error and return if it succeeded or not
{
    if (!isascii(c))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error. Not an ASCII character.\n.");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!isdigit(c))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error. Not a number.\n.");
        return 1;
    }
    // potentially more checks
    return 0;
}

int printASCIINumber() // So that here we just have to verify the success
{
   char c;
   c = getc(stdin);
   if (checkASCII(c))
      putc(c, stdout);
   else return 1;
   return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**

```
int checkASCII(char c) // Here we just check errors regardless of what failed
{
    if (!isascii(c))
      return 1;
    if (!isdigit(c)
      return 1;
    ... // potentially more checks
    return 0;
}

int printASCIINumber() // And here we verify success and print a general error message
{
   char c;
   c = getc(stdin);
   if (checkASCII(c))
      putc(c, stdout);
   else 
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error. Please input an ASCII number.\n");
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If there is any **objective** improvement to be made I am not against it too. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, change all `char`s to `int`s (all those functions are expecting an `int`) `getc` wants an in order to catch `EOF`, and ctype family functions too.

Comment: `if (!checkASCII(c))` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Only checking failure because checking both failure and success is useless ?

Comment: My comment is that it is the opposite of what it intends.

Comment: Only react to `checkASCII` returning false ? Please explain yourself

Comment: Actually run the program and see what happens.

Comment: Point of interest concerning portability: `isascii()` is not in the Standard Library, but is a BSD extension in gcc, and is in POSIX. [The POSIX Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isascii.html) marks `isascii()` as obsolescent, and states that this function may be removed from future versions.

Comment: Why are you checking for both `isascii()` and `isdigit()`? All digits are ascii so anything you pass to your function, will return `0` if it is a digit or `1` if it is not a digit (no matter if it is an ascii non-digit or a non-ascii non-digit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At very first: Your return values do not match the checks you make afterwards. If you consider the result being an error code, 0 indicating success, then you have to test via `if(!checkASCII(c))` - if you consider the result a boolean value then you need to invert the values returned. I'd recommend in this case including `<stdbool.h>`, changing the return type to `bool` and rename the function to `isASCII`. This would make your intention more obvious.

Comparing your two versions, I'd say none of both is superior to the other one in general – it rather depends on the circumstances you are programming under.

Imagine you are writing some general purpose library. Then I certainly would prefer variant 2, because you do not know if console output is desired by whoever uses your library – or if console is available at all (linux daemon processes, windows services, etc). For whichever reason, the user might want to use its own logging facility instead...

On the other hand, if you write some helper function used within your program only, variant 1 can be more handy:

- You can provide more fine grained output directly in the function directly where failure occurs - without having to evaluate some errno or return value outside your function (which could be the way of the library function to give further information about what went wrong).
- It is convenient, espcially if your checking function is called frequently, to be able to rely on logging already been done when you call your test function, so you can just go on in your code.

Comment: If I had to write a library, would adding a parameter for a stream to print errors in **Version 1** be a good idea ? Or setting a global const variable which would be called in every checking function ?

Comment: @Badda By adding a stream parameter, you force the user to provide one - even if he does not want to have any logging/output at all -- or the stream might be incompatible to his own logging system, so he would have to work around this problem in any suitable way (like creating his own stream implementation, which might be inefficient). Global variable - well, it cannot be const, else you cannot set it... But for exactly this purpose, there *is* already one: `errno` (include `errno.h`). Advantage of: (typically!) it is threadsafe, as there is one instance per thread...

Comment: @Badda By the way - streams are a C++ concept, it is a little more difficult to get such flexibility with C. You most likely will have to work with one or more function pointers so that the user can provide his own logging. E. g. to be able to pass in printf directly, it might look like this: `void test(int n, int (*loggingCallback)(char const*, ...))`. But I stay with - I rather wouldn't do it. And another argument: what, if user want's to internationalise the output (e. g. for German or Spanish users)?